# How to Use WaitHandle in WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

I do have two methods like the following

```
private void UpdateGrid(ServiceRef.GetCampaignInfoArrayCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (CampaignStatusGrid.DataSource == null || e == null || e.Result == null)
                return;
    UpdateLocalCampaignList(sManager.campinfotmp, e.Result, null);
    sManager.campinfo = DeepCopy(sManager.campinfotmp);
    int index = CampaignStatusView.FocusedRowHandle;
    CampaignStatusGrid.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { CampaignStatusGrid.DataSource = sManager.campinfo; }));
    CampaignStatusGrid.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { CampaignStatusView.FocusedRowHandle = index; }));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException))
                Program.ReConnect();
     else
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exception Message:\n{0}\n\nInnerException Message:\n{1}\n\nStackTrace:\n{2}",
                    ex.Message, ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "None", ex.StackTrace));
        }
}

private bool RunSSIS(string SsisPackagePath)
{
.....
}
```

first method, runs Asynchronously and updates a girdview datasource, and second method directly calls by user.
I do not use any threading tasks.
The problem I've, is when I call RunSSIS methods it takes between 5 to 20  minutes to be able get result.
but in meanwhile asynch method runs every 5 to 10 seconds

I know I should use sort of WaitHandle inside a Asynch method to wait for any in progress calls, but I don't know how.

Thank you

Comment: What does your `RunSSIS()` method do? How does it get the result?

Comment: @dymanoid It runs SSIS package, Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Task class with async and wait.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx